# How can I add a custom allure report with jbhave

Tags: allure, jbehave

I am trying to use allure report with jbehave on Java using maven. So there is a package that has a [java class](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-java/blob/master/allure-jbehave/src/main/java/io/qameta/allure/jbehave/AllureJbehave.java) that we can use to create the allure report.

I only imported that class and I added the class as a reportBuilder for the configuration of Jbehave, just like the code below.

```
...
import io.qameta.allure.jbehave.AllureJbehave
...

public class RunStories extends JUnitStories {

 private AllureJbehave allureJBehave;
 ...
 ...


 @Override
 public Configuration configuration() {

  // set path of results
  System.setProperty("allure.results.directory", "build/allure-results")

  // create AllureJbehave instance
  allureJBehave = new AllureJbehave();
  StoryReporterBuilder reporterBuilder = new StoryReporterBuilder()
   .withReporters(allureJBehave)
   .withCodeLocation(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()));
 
  // create and return configuration instance
  Configuration jBehaveConfiguration = new MostUsefulConfiguration();
   jBehaveConfiguration
     .useStoryReporterBuilder(reporterBuilder);

   return jBehaveConfiguration;
 }

}
```

But I am not getting the information for trends graphs, how can I add those values or add more information to the allure report ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the [plugin file (allure.yml)](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_existing_plugins) you are using for Allure. in case there is none, you can add your own with the list of plugins you are interested to use and add it to your configuration.

You can also check the read access of your files. If you are using Jenkins (for example), sometimes there is some access rights that are inherited and that can cause some issues when read.